# read system call returns -1 when reading from pipe in child process

Tags: c

To learn how Pipe IPC mechanism works, I wrote a simple program that creates two child processes which share data using a pipe. The first child process has to read data from a file and pass it to the pipe.

Afterwards, the second child process has to read it, convert it to uppercase and write it to another file. The read system call in the second child process returns -1 when reading from the pipe. Also when I execute the program, in some cases `printf` in the first child does not print anything and in other cases `printf` in the second child does not print, too. Could you please point the mistakes in the program which are causing the problems?

```c
int main(int args[], char * argv[]) {

    int fd[2];

    long length;
    char buff1[250];
    char buff2[250];

    FILE * fptr1;
    FILE * fptr2;

    pid_t A, B;
    pipe(fd);

    A = fork();

    if (A == -1) {
        printf("error in fork of A\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (A == 0) {
        fptr1 = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // program receives file names as argument

        if (fptr1 == NULL) {
            printf("Erro in file open1\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        fseek(fptr1, 0 L, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell(fptr1);
        fseek(fptr1, 0 L, SEEK_SET);

        close(fd[0]);

        fread(buff1, length, 1, fptr1);
        buff1[length] = '\0';
        printf("buff1 = %s", buff1);
        write(fd[1], buff1, length);

        fclose(fptr1);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        B = fork();
        if (B == -1) {
            printf("Error in forking child B");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (B == 0) {
            fptr2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");

            if (fptr2 == NULL) {
                printf("Error in file open2\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            close(fd[1]);
            int n = read(fd[0], buff2, length);
            printf("n = %d\n", n);
            upper_string(buff2); // converts characters to uppecase
            fwrite(buff2, 1, length, fptr2);
            fclose(fptr2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems `length` is undefined in the second child since it’s not set anywhere. Undefined behavior, might be zero if lucky so nothing is ever read from the pipe.

Comment: It's much easier to avoid this sort of problem if you split the parent and child code paths (after `fork`) into different functions. Having one big function with local variables declared at the top but initialized on only some code paths is always troublesome.

Comment: Oh, and if `read` returns -1, you should really try printing `errno`.

Comment: Setting `length` for second child solved undefined behavior. Also I added two calls to `wait()` in parent process, so that now  program does not hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to take into account here. First thing i would like to point is that you do not need to use two fork() calls. In that case you have three processes working in parallel (parent process and two child process, one per each fork() call).

One important point to take into account when you work with processes working in parallel is synchronism. In your code you are creating two processes. Parent process does not wait for any of its child, so it finishes its execution, and if child processes have not finished, they will become child of init process. But appart from that, you have the typical producer consumer problem. One of your child produce something and the other consume it, but how they work in parallel, consumer need to know that the product is ready to be consumed. So, in this case,  i think the easiest way to do this job is to use just one fork(), so child become the producer and the parent process (the consumer) wait until its child finish the job.